# How does China see the Ukrainian crisis?

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, china, ukraine, nato

From [Politico's report on the discussion between Joe Biden and Xi Jinping](https://www.politico.com/news/2022/03/18/bidens-call-with-xi-bilateral-deadlock-00018622)

> What the US should do is to seriously reflect on its role in the Ukraine crisis and the part it has played, effectively assume its due responsibilities, and take practical actions to ease the situation and solve the problem, instead of continuing to add fuel to the fire and shifting problems,” Chinese foreign ministry spokesperson Zhao Lijian said. “As the culprit of the Ukraine crisis, why does the US keep smearing China instead of reflecting on the security predicament in Europe caused by the eastward expansion of US-led NATO".

What exactly does China reproach to the US (besides the NATO expansion)? How does the Chinese position differ from the Russian one?

Comment: "What exactly does China reproach to the US" in relation to Ukraine, or more broadly? Why do you think there has to be something else besides NATO expansion in Ukraine?

Comment: @Fizz in relation to Ukraine - I hoped it would be clear frim the title and the context. The quoted fragment seems to suggest some American involvement un this specific crisis, rather than general evens of the last 30 years.

Comment: Russia has implied that it might start WWIII over their "special military operation" in Ukraine. China has a very long border with Russia, so China antagonizing Russia would not be a good idea. In addition, siding with Ukraine might imply that China should rethink whether Taiwan should be independent. However, given the near uniform international support for Ukraine, China does not want to antagonize the rest of the world. It appears to me that China is trying very hard to walk a tightrope.

Comment: @DavidHammen *near uniform international support for Ukraine* China and India make for about one third of the world population and a big part of the world GDP, so *uniform support* is an exaggeration.

Comment: @RogerVadim India is also trying to walk a tightrope.

Comment: @DavidHammen *walking a tightrope*? You mean by defying the US?

Comment: @RogerVadim Not trying to antagonize either Russia or the West. It's not just the US. If anything, it is Western Europe that is leading the charge here rather than the US.

Comment: @DavidHammen Just in case: I am not looking for a fight. I find that some clichées coming from the US press or officials are problematic... but it is not a place for such a discussion.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the questions is slightly unclear, but assuming it's only asking what China reproaches the US vis-a-vis of Ukraine (instead of what they reproach the US more broadly), and depending who is "China" exactly, the Chinese (state-controlled, obvious) media and diplomats have pretty much [repeated](https://www.politifact.com/factchecks/2022/mar/10/instagram-posts/china-repeats-false-claim-us-has-biolabs-ukraine/) the Russian allegations that the US was making biological weapons in Ukraine.

> A March 9 post on Instagram describes remarks from China’s Ministry of Foreign Affairs spokesperson Zhao Lijian, who said on March 9 that the U.S. has such biolabs in Ukraine.
>
> The post is a screenshot of Zhao at a podium with text that says, "China urges Pentagon to disclose alleged ‘biolabs’ in Ukraine ‘as soon as possible.’" The text also says, "Beijing believes the laboratories in Ukraine are just the ‘tip of an iceberg,’" and the U.S. controls 336 biological laboratories in 30 countries around the world.
>
> A caption on the post reads, "Russia found over 30 biological labs (with evidence of bioweapons) in Ukraine formed by the Pentagon in areas bordering Russia. If true, this is more than a bit concerning."

I can't recall if China has repeated the Russian allegations of genocide in high-profile venues, but if you look at CGTN's coverage of the war, they reflect the Russian position that it's a defensive action by Russia [in the Donbass region](https://youtu.be/nmGEVIAZZqc?t=161), with various strange stories like how an Ukrainian tank was driving around trying to suffocate civilians [in their basements] with its exhaust. (Slight exceptions to this: they recently reproduced the Russian claim to have fired a hypersonic weapon in Western Ukraine, but no images/video was shown. Earlier they've shown the similar missile strike on the "Ukraine-NATO base" near Lviv.) Chinese censors have [removed](https://edition.cnn.com/2022/03/18/asia/wang-jixian-chinese-vlogger-ukraine-intl-hnk/index.html) social posts from (Chinese users still in Ukraine) who show bombings in other places, or even show civil preparations by Ukrainians to resist.

On the web, [Global Times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Times) has articles [like](https://www.globaltimes.cn/page/202203/1254217.shtml) "Evidence suggests US may have supported neo-Nazi Azov Battalion" (March 7), which are pretty close to the Russian messaging that the war is about de-nazifying Ukraine, but also alleging US support for the said (neo-)Nazis.

Comment: That last Global Times article has pretty convincing evidence that pans out with a cursory search. Though clearly it does support China's agenda. Anything out there that would disprove it?